How can I get the name of a test in a tokio context?
I would like the name of the test that is running.
#[traced_test]
#[tokio::test]
async fn foo() {
    assert!(true);
    println!("test name is: {}", ???);
}

How do I get the test's name?
It should also work in all functions that the test calls:
async fn bar() {
    println!("bar: test name is: {}", ???);
}
async fn foo() {
    bar().await;
}

where "bar: test name is: foo" should be printed. Or "bar: test name is: <mod>::foo".

Is there a way to get the name within a test at all? If so, the solution would be the same.

Why do you want this? What would this knowledge enable you to do?

std::thread::current().name().unwrap() gives the name of the test if it is not a tokio test.

Why I want to do this? Because many tests require cryptoggraphic proofs that are expensive to build and I want to reuse them. If a proof is not available, I want to know which one it is, as it means that the test is not deterministic, as it should be.

I cannot reproduce it; metadata has a value and it contains the name of the test. Could you please share your Cargo.toml?

If you are using tokio::spawn, that task being spawned will end up on a tokio worker thread and therefore thread::current().name() wouldn't work there.

Those are tests so each start alone and can output the name before its spawn

The first option you tried working.
You just need to show output:
cargo test --  --nocapture <- this is the change
cargo.toml :
[dependencies]
tokio = {version = "1.40.0", features = ["full"]}
tracing = "0.1.40"
tracing-test = "0.2.5"

main.rs :
use tracing_test::traced_test;

#[traced_test]
#[tokio::test]
async fn foo() {
    bar();
}
fn bar() {
    let thread = std::thread::current();
    println!("{}", thread.name().unwrap());
}

// Avoid - just to cancel warnings
fn main() {
    bar();
}

Output:
test foo ... ok

successes:

---- foo stdout ----
foo


successes:
    foo

Edit for the last question edit:
use function_name::named;
use tracing_test::traced_test;
#[traced_test]
#[tokio::test]
#[named]
async fn foo() {
    let test_name = function_name!();
    println!("test name is: {}", test_name);
    assert!(true);
}

Result:
test name is: foo

It only works if the test is not annotated with #[tokio::test], which most of my tests are.

Added my code - please look

This works for almost all my tests. Trying to figure out why name resolution test-name resolution fails in some cases.

you can share the failing ones and ill check

This one fails to get the test name. Notice that it's not on the master branch. https://github.com/Neptune-Crypto/neptune-core/blob/asz/transaction-consensus/src/models/state/archival_state.rs#L984

Ran your code with --nocapture and it works appropriately. Edited my answer.

The thing is that it's probably get lost till the end of the run, --nocapture force it to output immediately.

Did you run the entire test? On my machine it's sometimes resolving to "unknown" and other times, it gives the right test name. And both happen within the execution of the same test.

I log it at the beginning of the test, the whole test should not affect it. Nocapture log immediately

I agree it shouldn't change throughout the test. But it does. Very weird.

What is the need behined it? Maybe we are having XY problem here

I have a server that serves the cryptographic proofs if they cannot be retrieved from disk. If execution of the test suite continues to request proofs, that would indicate that the test creates proof in a non-deterministic way. So I wanted to send the test name to the proof server to see which tests were non-deterministic. I want to root out all such cases, as the test suite otherwise takes too long to rung.

So why not using logger? why you need the stdout of the tests itself? You add a lot of extra noise to the test, you need to clean the results and collect them, and its not fits for doing stuff in multithreaded runtime.

I'm running the tests with cargo nextest. I wonder if that could be part of the reason?

The model is quite different then usual cargo test, all the tests are running together instead of binary by binary. But also the usual run tests in parallel so im not sure there's a difference in your case. But there's few approaches you can take, or a logger with global awareness, or the name as a parameter to pass everywhere around, which is unclean and annoying.

Hi! Simplified the question since I couldn't quite get to the bottom of this. Let's base the bounty on this simpler question.

It's about the challenge, not the bounty, but anyhow, edited with what seems to me like a kinda clean solution I found, and this macro might solve your issue since it's probably put the names in compile time.

The problem disappeared when I upgraded dependencies. It was probably in tokio or tokio_test where the spawned test tasks now just get the name of the test instead of the default tokio-runtime-worked. So: I don't have this problem anymore!

From which version to which? I'm curious about the causes. And you'd like to have a big test logging challenge, I'm dealing with a big one right now :).

tokio 1.37.0 to tokio 1.41.0.
